# Import.meta.env undefined on production build vitejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite

I am using vitejs to compile my react app statically, however after build .env imports become undefined which is not the case on development stage.

reading the docs I've found out that these variables are replace by their corresponding values, but upon looking at the source/compiled code in the dev tools after serving it shows an empty object with the env name/key

[image]

i might have a wrong configuration in vite.config.ts so here it is.

```js
//vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import { getAliases } from 'vite-aliases';

const aliases = getAliases({
  path: 'src',
  prefix: '@',
});

export default ({ mode }) => {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };

  // import.meta.env.VITE_NAME available here with: process.env.VITE_NAME
  // import.meta.env.VITE_PORT available here with: process.env.VITE_PORT

  const plugins = mode === 'development' ? [reactRefresh()] : [];
  return defineConfig({
    plugins,
    publicDir: 'src/assets',
    resolve: {
      alias: aliases,
    },
    build: {
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1500,
    },
  });
};
```

And also the code where I'm referencing these env var

```js
//config.ts
export const config = () => {
  const url = import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL;
  const api = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT;
  const auth = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_ENDPOINT;

  const isProd = import.meta.env.MODE === 'production';
  const isDev = import.meta.env.MODE === 'development';

  console.log(url, api, auth);
  return {
    api: (endpoint: string) => `${url}${api}${endpoint}`,
    auth: (endpoint: string) => `${url}${auth}${endpoint}`,
    test: (endpoint: string) => `${url}test${endpoint}`,
    isProd,
    isDev,
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have followed the docs and hit the same problem, import.meta.env is always empty, dev or production. I have an `.env.local` it has key/value in the format `VITE_KEY=VALUE` and I access them with `import.meta.env.VITE_KEY`

Comment: I kinda forgot how i did it but you can look at my config. https://pastebin.com/04FGwEgw

Comment: @vexingCoder thanks for the pastebin link, 99% solved my issues (which matched @fungus1487). After adapting your good code, I had a bug reported in the browser.console and opened the related vite code link. It showed the viteEnv value enclosed by parentheses - (). I added stringify around the value and wambam bug resolved !  `viteEnv[`import.meta.env.${key}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[key])`

Answer (score 46):

I just realized what the [ViteJS documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) says and I'll leave it in case someone also suffers from this.

> To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with `VITE_` are exposed to your Vite-processed code

[image]

Comment: This fixed my problem!  I had switched from building with React (e.g. `react-scripts build`) to Vite.  I also had to change my REACT_APP_* environment variables to VITE_*.  I also had to change `process.env.` to `import.meta.env.` (see https://blog.ramadevsign.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vite-react-template-example) and add the `"types": ["vite/client"]` into the `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json file (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3524#issuecomment-848641926)

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to use `VITE_`.  You can use any prefix you like as long as you define it in the `envPrefix` option on the vite config.

Comment: You can also use [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables) which is useful if you want to use the same variable elsewhere and a common prefix isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Change your vite.config file to load env.
It is given in the documentation here, https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    // vite config
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV),
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I moved my .env file to the root directory of my project. I placed mine in src folder that's why it was undefined

Answer (score 1):

First be sure your `.env` file is in the *root* of your project. Not in the `src` folder (as I thought at the beginning).

Also be sure your key name starts with `VITE_`, as [the documentation says](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-files).

Then you have to activate this in your `vite.config.ts` based on ["Using Env variables doc"](https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config):

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    // vite config
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV),
    },
  }
})
```

But then your Vue3 application won't work, you have to activate the `vue` plugin, and the src alias. This is my final `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  return {
    plugins: [
      vue(),
    ],
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV),
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    }
  }
});
```